# How do I download multiple dynamic files using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to download multiple dynamic files with ruby from a website.
There are five different files and they all have a basic structure:

backup_**YYYY**-**MM**-**DD**-**HHMM**_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_**ID**-**CONTENT**.**ENDING**

All the bold written parts are dynamic and have to be replaced.

The files could look like this:

```
backup_2017-03-06-1020_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-db.gz
backup_2017-03-06-1020_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-others.zip
backup_2017-03-06-1020_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-plugins.zip
backup_2017-03-06-1020_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-themes.zip
backup_2017-03-06-1020_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-uploads.zip
```

Could someone help?

Edit: 
I tried a non-dynamic version of it which wont work long, though:

```
puts 'Starting Download...'
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.start("jr-addons.de") do |http|
    resp = http.get("/btemp/backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-db.gz")
    open("backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-db.gz", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
    resp = http.get("/btemp/backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-others.zip")
    open("backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-others.zip", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
    resp = http.get("/btemp/backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-plugins.zip")
    open("backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-plugins.zip", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body) 
    end
    resp = http.get("/btemp/backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-themes.zip")
    open("backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-themes.zip", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body) 
    end
    resp = http.get("/btemp/backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-uploads.zip")
    open("backup_2016-10-23-1520_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-uploads.zip", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
end
puts 'Done.'
```

Comment: Can you please add some code. what have you tried yet?

Comment: Google "ruby string interpolation"

Comment: @DeepakMahakale edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DATES = %w|03-06-1020|
SUFFIXES = %w|db others plugins themes uploads|

puts 'Starting Download...'
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.start("jr-addons.de") do |http|
  DATES.product(SUFFIXES).each do |(date, suffix)|
    file = "/foo_#{date}_bar-#{suffix}.baz"
    puts file
    # do other stuff with this file
  end
end
```

Comment: I am just curious why `%w||` instead of `%w()` ?

Comment: any specific reason?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale nope, no specific reason, just a matter of habit, since arrays of words in parentheses occur way more often than words with vertical bars.

Comment: @mudasobwa `%w(that's(not) a(problem) if (parens) are (always matched))`

Comment: @EricDuminil wow! I did not know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example for string interpolation with time and strings.

You'd just need to define an array with the required dates, ids and extensions, and iterate :

```
time = Time.new(2017, 3, 6, 10, 20)
id = '2867ed5aba3d'
content = 'db'
ext = 'gz'

puts time.strftime("backup_%Y-%m-%d-%H%M_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_#{id}-#{content}.#{ext}")
#=> backup_2017-03-06-1020_JRAddOns_Die_Pflegeserie_fr_2867ed5aba3d-db.gz
```